Cannot change or use global variables in C# (WinForms .NET)
I've declared a few int variables inside public partial class Form1 : Form in C#. However, i can't use or change them if it isn't done inside a function (e. g. inside of private void button1_click), as if the variables never existed. It gives a ""IDE1007: The name 'r' does not exist in the current context" error when trying to change tha value of r. That said, I can't create a pen using Pen dot = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));, trying to do so gives another error, "CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property from "Form1.r"" (I'm trying to make a sort of MS Paint clone).
Here's a snippet from my code:
int r = 0;
int g = 0;
int b = 0;
int size = 2;

Pen dot = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
Pen rect = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
Pen pencil = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
string curpen = "";

Here are some screenshots with the errors:

name 'r' doesn't exist in current context:



A field initializer cannot reference <..>


Tried updating VS. Didn't help. Any ideas?

The assignment must be inside a method. You cannot put statements at class level. After all, when would you expect them to be executed?

in C#, you cannot initialize a member variable using another member variable outside of a method.
To fix your issue, you can either make the ints r,g,b all static (you probably don't want this...), or you can use the constructor to initialize your Pens.
Something like this:
public class Form1 : Form {
    int r, g, b = 0;
    Pen dot = null;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        dot = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
    }
} 

The constructor is executed once your Form is created. It is the place to put initialization logic.

It looks there are two issues here. First you can only declare and initialize a variable in a class (in your case r is a private variable declared). You cannot bind it to a variable again outside a method. You are trying to assign 0 to r outside a method. You can do so only inside methods or properties. Second issue is your are calling a static method(Color.FromArgb) by sending a non-static values (r,g,b) , this is not allowed you can only use non-static fields for a non-static methods. (static fields can be sent to a non-static methods). Please refer some tutorials about C#. Hope this helps

This is not true: you are allowed to pass a static field or property to an instance method and even to use a static member inside an instance method. What you cannot do is to access instance members inside of a static method, because you always need a reference to the instance (this).
